# Get statistics of a dataframe according to a list and a groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataframe with 2 columns - column message is a column made by lists with tokens (words) and score is a numeric column

```
Message                Score  Month
["a", "a", "b", "c"]   5      1
["a", "b", "d", "e"]   4      1
["b", "b", "d", "e"]   4      1
```

and I have a list with some words:

```
l = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

I need the average score for each word in the list for month. Therefore, if word "a" is in 2 rows in my dataframe, it should return the average of this 2 rows. The expected result should be:

```
month word  avg_score
1      a     4.5   #--> it's in first and second row of my dataframe, so avg = (5+4)/2 in  
1      b     4.33  #--> it's in first, second and third row of my dataframe, so avg =(5+4+4)/3
1      c     5     #--> it's in first row of my dataframe, so avg =(5)/1
1      d     4.5   #--> it's in second and third row of my dataframe, so avg =(5+4)/2
1      e     4.5   #--> it's in second and third row of my dataframe, so avg =(5+4)/2
```

*My attempt*

I managed only to calculate it per word, not month. Probably because I'm alocating numbers in a dictionary, however I don't know another way to do so.

```
dicts = {}

for item in l:
  df_new_2 = df[df['Word'].apply(lambda x: item in x)]
  mean = df_new.Score.mean()
  dicts[item] = mean
  
df_new = pd.DataFrame(dicts.items(), columns=['word', 'avg_score'])
df_new
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your dataframe

```
df
    Message     Score  Month
0   [a, a, b, c]    5  1
1   [a, b, d, e]    4  1
2   [b, b, d, e]    4  1
```

Since we only care about unique entries, we can convert to set to remove duplicates

```
df['Message']=df['Message'].apply(set)
df
    Message         Score   Month
0   {a, c, b}       5       1
1   {a, e, b, d}    4       1
2   {e, b, d}       4       1
```

Then explode our sets into rows and re-group them to get your mean per unique entry

```
df.explode('Message').groupby(['Month','Message']).mean()
                Score
Month   Message 
1      a        4.500000
       b        4.333333
       c        5.000000
       d        4.000000
       e        4.000000
```